# How to avoid generate the same java file with swagger gen

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

Let us suppose we have some yaml files like following:

**Article.yml**

```
GenericArticleDto:
  type: object
  properties:
    description: 
      type: string
[...]
```

**Order.yml**

```
EnglishArticleDto:
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '../Article.yml/components/schemas/GenericArticleDto'
[...]
```

I generate the Java classes from the Order.yml with *swagger gen* and specify the destination package, let's say 'com.test.order'
After this operation I have two classes in com.test.order, *EnglishArticleDto.java* and *GenericArticleDto.java*

If I have another yml file with a dto that point to the same object *GenericArticleDto*

**Proposal.yml**

```
CustomerArticleDto:
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '../Article.yml/components/schemas/GenericArticleDto'
```

I generate the Java classes from the Proposal.yml and specify the destination package, let's say 'com.test.proposal'. If I run the swagger script I have two classes in com.test.proposal, *CustomerArticleDto.java* and *GenericArticleDto.java*

My doubt is:
Is there a way with swagger gen to specify to avoid the creation of another Java class for *GenericArticleDto* and to **REUSE** the same present under the package com.test.order?

**Swagger gen version: 2.2**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be specific, I am exactly referring to this issue https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2701 and I am not aware about further news about it